# I am getting this [object HTMLSpanElement] on my html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tags

The problem is solved no need to go thorough the post thanks for the help the useful time is appreciated.

Comment: The variable `res` isnt set anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are referencing this DOM object (`<span id = "res"></span>`) itself but you don't want this object but the text which is stored inside.

You would get this value with a simple

```js
document.getElementById("res").innerText
```

That's more or less the same call you are using to set the text of this `res` object.

So a working example could look like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Exercise 2 </title>
</head>
<body>
<form>

Enter the  value to be  converted <br><br> <input type="numbers" id="val" /> <br><br>
<input type="button" onClick="celtofar()" Value="Celcius to Fahrenhet" id="b1" /><br><br>
<input type="button" onClick="fartocel()" Value="Fahrenhet to Celcius" id="b2"/><br><br>

Output : <br>
<span id = "res"></span>
<p id= "op"></p>

</form>
<style type="text/css">
body { margin-left: 450px; margin-top: 100px}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function celtofar()
{
    v = document.getElementById("val").value;

    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = (v * 1.8) + 32;
    
    var message = v +'\xB0C is ' + document.getElementById("res").innerText + '\xB0F.';
    document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = message;
    
}
function fartocel() 
{ 
    v = document.getElementById("val").value;
  
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = (v - 32) / 1.8;
    
    var message = v +'\xB0F is ' + document.getElementById("res").innerText + '\xB0C.';
    document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = message;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Read more about this here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: You could also refactor by selecting `res` just once: `cons res = document.getElementById("res")` and then set with `res.innerHTML = ...` and get with `res.innerText`

Comment: @Emre Sure, but that wasn't part of the question. And there is much more potential for refactoring and reworking.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to close the span after the `<p></p>` tag.  Just put the closing `</span>` after the `</p>`

```
<span id = "res">
<p id= "op"></p></span>
```